# kotlin null handle in map to data class

Tags: android, kotlin

`bigPicture` is null sometimes. how to handle this?

App crash : `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key bigPicture is missing in the map.`

```
data class NotificationModel(val version: String?,
                             val bigPicture: String?,
                             val title: String?,
                             val body: String?,
                             val messageData:String?,
                             val groupKey: String?) {
    companion object {
        fun from(map: Map<String?, String?>) = object {
            val version by map
            val bigPicture by map
            val title by map
            val body by map
            val groupKey by map
            val messageData by map

            val data = NotificationModel(version, bigPicture, title, body,messageData, groupKey)
        }.data
    }
}
```

Comment: You can go through this article - https://medium.com/@atomcat1978/wanna-kotlin-and-map-delegation-read-this-first-a5695d3ab98b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `key` is not present in the `map` then only we get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key bigPicture is missing in the map`. Look:

```
    val map = mutableMapOf<String?,String?>()
    map["version"] = "1.1"
    //map["bigPicture"] = "my BigPic" // app crash because no key is present
    map["bigPicture"] = null  // No crash here as key is present but value is null
    map["title"] = "My Title"
    map["body"] = "My Body"
    map["groupKey"] = "Group key"
    map["messageData"] = "My Msg Data"
    val notificationModel = NotificationModel.from(map)
    Log.d("TAG==>>","BigPicture = ${notificationModel.bigPicture}  ")
}
```

To avoid crash you may try below code:

```
    data class NotificationModel(val version: String?,
                             val bigPicture: String?,
                             val title: String?,
                             val body: String?,
                             val messageData:String?,
                             val groupKey: String?) {
    companion object {
        fun from(map: MutableMap<String?, String?>) = object {
            val version by map
            val bigPicture = if (map.containsKey("bigPicture")) map["bigPicture"] else ""
            val title by map
            val body by map
            val groupKey by map
            val messageData by map

            val data = NotificationModel(version, bigPicture, title, body,messageData, groupKey)
        }.data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin they provide two methods for getting value from a Map

1. `myMap.get(key)` or `mayMap[key]` :  returns the value if it exists or returns null if it doesn't
2. `myMap.getValue(key)`: returns the value for the key or throws an `NoSuchElementException` if the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of null check is what the [`Elvis operator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) is for:

```
val bigPicture = map["bigPicture"] ?: ""
```